# RestKit delete semantics

Tags: core-data, restkit

What are the delete semantics for RestKit when using it with Core Data?

For example, assume I correctly set a `primaryKeyAttribute` in RestKit for Organization entities.  If I do a GET on, say, `/organizations/` I get entries for `/organizations/1/`, `/organizations/2/`, and `/organizations/3/` back.  Let's say I do a GET on `/organizations/` a bit later and only get entries for `/organizations/1/` and `/organizations/3/` back.  `/organizations/2/ has been deleted on the server.

I would expect RestKit to delete my Core Data record for `/organizations/2/`.  Is this what RestKit does or do I have to implement this behavior?  Does this change in any way if I am using the reboot-networking-layer branch?  Are there any settings in RestKit I should be aware of that affect this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement FetchRequests in order for those objects to be deleted. Here is a simple example:

```
    [objectManager addFetchRequestBlock:^NSFetchRequest *(NSURL *URL) {
    RKPathMatcher *pathMatcher = [RKPathMatcher pathMatcherWithPattern:@"/organizations"];

    NSDictionary *argsDict = nil;
    BOOL match = [pathMatcher matchesPath:[URL relativePath] tokenizeQueryStrings:NO parsedArguments:&argsDict];

    if (match) {
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Organization"];
        return fetchRequest;
    }

    return nil;
}];
```

I do this in the ApplicationDelegate(the same place I setup RestKit). After you do it there, all other calls will automatically delete orphaned objects.